# Correcting singular value in sequence of equal values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with month and days and corresponding cycle (warm/cold/transition)
example :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cycle':['transition'] * 10 + 
['warm'] * 1 + ['transition'] * 3 + ['warm'] * 10})
```

I would like to find singular values (ie. warm) after a sequence of equal 10 consecutive rows (ie. transition) and assign them the value of the previous string (ie. transition) if they are followed by the same sequence (ie. transition).

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a data example and what you have tried so far?

Comment: If there are more than 10 "transition" rows followed by 2 consecutive "warm" rows, do you want to change the 2 values or just one or neither?

Comment: Just the first one as the second warm is followed by 10 other similar values. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Creating given dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cycle':['transition'] * 10 + 
['warm'] * 1 + ['transition'] * 3 + ['warm'] * 10})
```

To find the indexes where the changes occured by grouping consecutive rows.

```
x = (df.groupby((df["cycle"] != df["cycle"].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 10 )
```

```
df.loc[((x - x.shift()) == -9)] = "change"
changed_indexes = df[df["cycle"] == 'change'].index
```

-9 values are important because this values mean there has been a change in this index and we are labeling these indexes.

```
for i in changed_indexes:
    df.iloc[i] = df.shift().iloc[i]
```

After that we are just changing the values of these indexes with the previous value.